# Artifactory: what is the cron expression syntax?

Tags: artifactory

I've created a remote repository and I'd like to enable the Activate Replication of the repository, but for some reason I don't get the cron expression validated.

If I input `5 4 * * *`, there'll be an error `The cron expression is invalid`.

[image]

I've read https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/CronTrigger

Does somebody know what's going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see references in the [CronTrigger Tutorial](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger#examples).

For example, the `0 0 12 * * ?` expression will fire at 12pm (noon) every day.

Comment: Thanks! Seems that adding `?` in the expression was the key. There seems to be a bug in Artifactory version 7.49.8, because the validator doesn't accept expression without the question mark.